# how to convert numeric to nvarchar in sql command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to convert a numeric value to nvarchar in sql command.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: If you don't have a copy of SQL Server Books Online on your computer, you can always [access it over the Internet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214%28v=sql.90%29.aspx "SQL Server 2005 Books Online"). Its navigation system is quite decent and should allow you to find answers to basic questions fairly quickly. Here's an article about T-SQL conversion functions: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 47):

```
select convert(nvarchar(255), 4343)
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 18):

```
declare @MyNumber int
set @MyNumber = 123
select 'My number is ' + CAST(@MyNumber as nvarchar(20))
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. if suppose MyNumber = 123.45 ... what will be my result.

Comment: conversion to nvarchar is the same, but use a different numeric data type like `decimal(5,2)`

Answer (score 6):

```
declare @MyNumber float 
set @MyNumber = 123.45 
select 'My number is ' + CAST(@MyNumber as nvarchar(max))
```

Answer (score 2):

If the culture of the result doesn't matters or we're only talking of integer values, `CONVERT` or `CAST` will be fine.

However, if the result must match a specific culture, `FORMAT` might be the function to go:

```
DECLARE @value DECIMAL(19,4) = 1505.5698
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @value)        -->  1505.5698
SELECT FORMAT(@value, 'N2', 'en-us')    --> 1,505.57
SELECT FORMAT(@value, 'N2', 'de-de')    --> 1.505,57
```

For more information on `FORMAT` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql).

Of course, formatting the result should be a matter of the UI layer of the software.